# Graph API facebook developer stories not accessible

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am playing with Graph API Facebook for Instagram. I want to get the stories first.

I have checked the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/) it says:

[image]

I am getting this:

[image]

Now I think I have the permissions and all, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Guess you are not actually dealing with an `IG User` object there then. (You're aware that this API is only for Business and Creator accounts, right?)

Comment: yes i have a instagram business account.. but it is still not giving me anything @CBroe

Comment: You might _have_ one, but it doesn't look like that particular ID you are using there, belongs to one.

Comment: correct that's random id - - the real id is 62942475166 @CBroe

Comment: i dont know i think i might link this page to facebook account? not sure

Comment: You need to get the IG business account, via the page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Comment: First your ig business account needs to be connected to a facebook page. Then, you can reach id ig business account from that page id. First, me/accounts then id_fb_page?fields=instagram_business_account call that endpoint. Then use id ig to call stories.